# Partial text visible in the topic request section

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, design, documentation-topics

There is some partial text visible issue in the documentation beta - topic request section.

Link for this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql-server/topics?tab=requests

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Partial text visible in the topic request]

Comment: This issue should be fixed in the next production build. Thanks for reporting it.

Comment: In the `rev 2017.2.22.25205` this issue is fixed